# MYSQL extremely difficult Select Query

Tags: mysql, database, date, join, between

So I have a scenario built around a driving school, within this driving school are staff members and they have different roles. I'm trying to find a way to check a specific staff members schedule for the upcoming couple of days or week. After an hour of Googling different variations of BETWEEN and JOINs I can't find one that allows me to get that 'schedule'.

This is the first attempt that I made where I've gone overkill with my ANDs and ORs:

```
SELECT staff.staff_id, lname, interviewstart, lessondate, lessontime, prac_date, prac_time
FROM staff, interviews, lessons, practicaltests
WHERE staff.staff_id = 6 AND lessondate OR practicaldate OR interviewstart  BETWEEN curdate() AND      '2014-12-21'
GROUP BY staff_id
```

lessondate and practical date are both of the DATE format and interviewstart is a DATETIME (I know this doesn't make too much of a difference but just so you know.)
This returned the messiest table I have ever seen and definitely didn't get the right info.
The results I'm expecting is something that would look like this:

```
staff_id    lesson date     practical date  interviewstart
6           2014-12-18      
6                           2014-12-19
6                                           2014-12-15 13:00:00
```

If that makes any sense, it would just make a basic list.

Please can someone try and help me here, I'm usually quite good at seeing a way to solve a problem but my MYSQL isn't up to scratch! (Also sorry if the code isn't displayed right, tried my best!)

Comment: Good explanation but having some sample data for all the tables could have made the question much better in terms of understanding and finding the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, the basic outcome I'm looking for is a way to display all date/date times that fall out within a range for one staff member (foreign key in each table).

Comment: Please post some relevant data inside each table. If you want a wonderful king solution it will make it much easier /possible if you provide data from each table

Comment: Your are missing join's between your tables, so I'm skeptical that you will readily fix this problem.  Simple rule:  *never* use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I'm working on an updated solution from E. Uta's answer below, should I make a new question or update this post? (New here so wanna abide to etiquette as best as I can.)

Answer (score 0):

You are making wrong use of the OR operator. Try this:

```
SELECT staff.staff_id, lname, interviewstart, lessondate, lessontime, prac_date, prac_time
FROM staff, interviews, lessons, practicaltests
WHERE staff.staff_id = 6 AND (lessondate BETWEEN curdate() AND '2014-12-21' OR practicaldate BETWEEN curdate() AND '2014-12-21' OR interviewstart  BETWEEN curdate() AND '2014-12-21') GROUP BY staff_id
```

Comment: Just used this, we have progress! It's stopped making the big messy list however it now prints out one line which finds the right staff member and last name. However the interview, practical date and lesson date it returns are all just the first value in those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider: 
- Use standard joining syntax ([INNER/LEFT/RIGHT] JOIN table ON join_condition 
- Use parenthesis for correct logic and to overcame the operator precedence (since AND is evaluated before OR) 
- If you use GROUP BY then all the columns included in the GROUP BY clause MUST be present in the select list (or viceversa).

The query below should help you (notice that you need to check the joining conditions)

```
SELECT staff.staff_id, lname, interviewstart, lessondate, lessontime, prac_date, prac_time
FROM staff
LEFT JOIN interviews
    ON staff.staff_id = interviews.staff_id
LEFT JOIN lessons
    ON staff.staff_id = lessons.staff_id
LEFT JOIN practicaltests
    ON staff.staff_id = practicaltests.staff_id 
WHERE staff.staff_id = 6 
AND (
    lessons.lessondate BETWEEN curdate() AND '2014-12-21'
    OR practicaltests.practicaldate BETWEEN curdate() AND '2014-12-21'
    OR interviews.interviewstart BETWEEN curdate() AND '2014-12-21'
)
```

Note: you can use `curdate()+7` instead of the hardcoded date(s) for example. This translate into adding 7 days to the current date.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This definitely made a positive change. The main problems now are that the entire interviewstart column says 'NULL' (but this staff member in particular doesn't have any interviews so could be correct) and the lessons and practical tests results alternate between all the results that staff member has.

Comment: @hateprogramming, ok, can you be more specific on what is incorrect ? Would it be possible to add more sample data to the question and state what is needed and what not from the original tables ? Of course, not real data.

Comment: Okay the basic outcome is a list that can be used to see a timetable for a staff member. The 3 areas he can be involved in are interviews, lessons and practical tests. The fields I will use are staff_id (INT), lname (VARCHAR), interviewstart (DATETIME), lessondate (DATE), lessontime (TIME), prac_date (DATE), prac_time (TIME). The first thing that is wrong is that it is printing a lesson, and a practical test on the same line instead of showing for example a lesson on the 17th at 12:00 then making a new line for a prac test the next day. The other problem is it shows results more than once .

Comment: Also would I still use curdate()+7 as BETWEEN curdate()+7 or does that change?

Comment: You should use that like for example: BETWEEN curdate() and curdate()+7

Comment: I see, thanks that looks much better! Let me know if you need anymore information about the data.